# $("123").ready (fn(){}) triggering no matter what

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem where the $().ready is triggering no matter what I put into the parameter which means that it actually triggers before the page is ready. I am using ASP.NET mixed in with EXT.NET and would like to implement jQuery to spice things up a little. As the description says, it triggers no matter what so if I put "123" into the paramter it will show me the alart() anyways. Here is the code is am running:

```
    $("123").ready(function () {
        var $kids = $("x-column-inner").children();
        alert($(".x-column-inner").height());
    });
```

As a result ".x-column-inner" is null because it hasn't finished compiling the page and is already executing the javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.ready` method ignores what is in the selector completely. It is only fired when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is triggered by the browser.

Note however that DOMContentLoaded may fire before images and css sheets are done loading, resulting in in-accurate height and width measurements. If that is an issue for you, you need to use `$(window).load();`

If the `DOMContentLoaded` event has already been triggered, the ready callback will be executed immediately.

Comment: Is there a way to force it to wait for everything else to load? It seems that ASP finishes loading the site first and then populates everything using the backend.

Comment: What is "everything else"? is it ajax? images? iframes? If it is images or iframes, you can use the `$(window).load()` method. Otherwise, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the period in your first selector:

```
$(function () {
    var $kids = $(".x-column-inner").children();
    alert($(".x-column-inner").height());
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Kevin is most likely correct. What isnt done loading? It is kind of hard to help without seeing any of the corresponding html.